Densities at a Point
I was recently reading Purcell’s text on electrodynamics. He generalizes Coulomb’s Law by introducing charge densities. However, what does the density at a point represent? (Since Purcell took charge density to be a function of $x$, $y$, and $z$.) My first thought was to take a small box surrounding a point P and measuring the mass/charge within it and dividing by the volume of the box. Then, I reasoned that I had to take the limit as the volume of the box approached zero to find the density at that point. However, mass and charge distributions aren’t continuous on the molecular scale, and it is instead simply a good approximation. And by my initial logic of taking a limit to find the density, this would mean that the density everywhere was zero apart from singularities. (Locations of the particles themselves.)

The more you think about this the more you will discover that the particle, or more precisely the corpuscle approximation, is not a good one and that it causes more pain over the long run than it's ultimately worth. The resolution to all of this at the microscopic level is that there are no mass and charge densities at the atomic scale. The world goes from classical to quantum mechanical and then everything is completely different.

You are on the right track. Matter and charge are often treated as continuous. It is a good approximation.
Air exerts a pressure on the walls. You think of it as a continuous fluid. In reality, the pressure is the hammer blows of lots of discrete atoms. You often don't have to worry about the microscopic details.

On that note, if we treat matter and charge as continuous, how can we have non-uniform distributions? Using the notion of individual particles, we understand that there can be a non-uniform distribution depending on their positions. How can we have ‘more’ of mass or charge in a particular region if we treat it as continuous? (sort of like a paint smear?)

Sure, if we pack the charges more tightly in one region vs. another, on a macroscopic scale, we'd say there's a nonuniform distribution. Your follow-up sounds like it's asking what would happen if actual, real charges were continuous distributions, however. Really, charge is just something that quantifies how strongly something interacts electrostatically (and magnetically, if it is moving). To say that there is more charge in one region of space than another for a continuous distribution is just stating that a particular area of space contributes more to the electric field produced.

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but unfortunately, if you're looking for a deeper answer, I may not be the best person to answer this.

It is a matter of approximation. Yes charges would not normally be concentrated into a point, but the specifics of charge distribution will normally contribute to second and third order effects.
For example, electron (in vacuum) can be treated as a point-charge and you will get the field it produces, according to Coulomb's law to a good approximation. Next order effects, such as theoretical electron's dipole moment, may be conceived of, and may even be attempted to be measured.
Another way to think about it is this. Often the effects of charges are calculated from integrals that look like this:
$$
\int d^3r \rho G
$$
Where $\rho$ is the charge density and $G$ is some function (Greens function, usually). This function is often well-behaved in the vicinity of the charge (lets say charge is at $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{0}$), i.e. it can be represented as some sort of power-series:
$$
\lim_{\mathbf{r}\to 0}G\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=G^{(0)}+r^\alpha G^{(1)}_\alpha+r^\alpha r^\beta G^{(2)}_{\alpha\beta}+\dots
$$
Where $G^{(0)}$ are constants, and I am using Einstein notation to denote summation $r^\alpha G^{(1)}_\alpha=x G^{(1)}_x+y G^{(1)}_y+z G^{(1)}_z$. So then you are finding integral of the following shape:
$$
\int d^3r \rho G=G^{(0)}\cdot\int_{r\to 0} d^3r \,\rho+G^{(1)}_{\alpha}\cdot\int_{r\to 0} d^3r \,r^\alpha \rho+\dots
$$
You will now see that I may as well replace $\rho \to Q\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)$, where $Q$ is the total charge, and get the effects due to $G^{(0)}$. Those are usually strongest. I can also replace:
$$
\rho=Q\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)-d^\beta\partial_\beta \delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)
$$
This will pick up the effects due to monopole ($Q$) as well as due to dipole ($\mathbf{d}$):
$$
\int d^3r \rho G=G^{(0)}Q+G^{(1)}_{\alpha}d^\alpha+\dots
$$
This way of breaking the complex charge density usually allows one to focus on things we can measure, and not worry about things that are unmeasurable.
You can understand $\rho=Q\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)$ as 'we only have enough experimental measurements to constrain the total charge, the effects due to shape could not be measured'. To measure shape effects you would need $G$ that does not behave nicely in the location of the charge, it has to have very rapid variations there, so that power series decomposition would not be well-behaved. Like a probe put right next to the charge.
